# mostrar exception erro no retorno da chamada AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, .net

Tenho essa chamada ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/Shipper/getFullAddress",
    data: {
        postalCode: value
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#AddressStreet').val(data.AddressStreet);
        $('#AddressNeighborhood').val(data.AddressNeighborhood);
        $('#AddressCity').val(data.AddressCity);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
})
```

que chama esse metodo:

[AjaxCall]

```
public JsonResult getFullAddress(string postalCode) {
    try {
        var address = getAddressByZipCode(postalCode);
        return Json(address, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
        return Json(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Queria mostrar a exception message na minha view, mas a minha chama me retorna isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parece q o json está errado em algum lugar

Comment: sim, e eu não sei aonde pode ser.

Comment: clica naquele 65.524 que aparece no console pra ver oq deu no json

Comment: Cara esse seu código acho que não vai ter o comportamento que você espera. Lá no javascript, como você trata o erro no servidor, não vai cair na função "error" do ajax. Eu vou postar uma resposta explicando o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você verificar o html que está sendo retornado no responseText, vai reparar que se trata de uma página de erro por causa do AllowGet, que você não colocou quando trata o erro.

O correto seria:

```
public JsonResult getFullAddress(string postalCode) {
try {
    var address = getAddressByZipCode(postalCode);
    return Json(address, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
} catch (System.Exception ex) {
    **return Json(ex.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);**
}
}
```

Com isso você resolve o problema do erro, mas caso você queira exibir a mensagem que está sendo retornada, você precisará rever o seu código, porque como você está retornando um texto na resposta, não vai passar pela função "error" do ajax já que efetivamente não ocorreu nenhum erro.